# Bluetooth Sniffer with Scapy

Tags: bluetooth, scapy, beacon, sniffer

I am interested in writing a simple sniffer with scapy to find the Bluetooth beacons in range and get their addresses and RSSI. I can find these for 802.11 but not much is there for Bluetooth. Could someone please point me in the right direction? TIA.